# Framework 7 Adjusting Tab Widths on Tabbar

Tags: html, css, html-framework-7

Is there a way to give weights to tab widths on tabbar on Framework7?

HTML code below would divide the tabbar into 3 equal-width tabs.

```
<div class="toolbar tabbar">
    <div class="toolbar-inner">
      <a href="#tab-1" class="tab-link tab-link-active">Left Tab</a>
      <a href="#tab-2" class="tab-link">Center Tab</a>
      <a href="#tab-3" class="tab-link">Right Tab</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Say I want left and right tab to span 25% of the tab bar width and center tab to span remaining 50%. How could I get this kind of behaviour by use of CSS or Framework7 API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply create two CSS classes and apply them to desired tab item.

CSS:

```
.w-25{
  width:25%!important;
}
.w-50{
  width:50%!important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="toolbar tabbar">
    <div class="toolbar-inner row">
      <a href="#tab-1" class="w-25 tab-link tab-link-active">Left Tab</a>
      <a href="#tab-2" class="w-50 tab-link">Center Tab</a>
      <a href="#tab-3" class="w-25 tab-link">Right Tab</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a working feed:
https://jsfiddle.net/42yLf4jt/4/